# How to add a regression line to a gganimate plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, gganimate

I would like to add a regression line to my gganimate plot. Without the regression the line the gganimate plot works as expected, and when I add the the geom_smooth command to the regular plot it works fine. I only receive an error when I try to add the regression line to the gganimate plot.

```
g <- ggplot(pdata, aes(x = ole, y = rsv)) + 
        geom_point(aes(color = region)) + 
        geom_smooth(aes(group = region, color = region), se = FALSE)

anim <- g + transition_states(region, transition_length = 3, state_length = 5) 
anim
```

I receive the error message:

```
 geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
Error in transform_path(all_frames, next_state, ease, params$transition_length[i],  : 
  transformr is required to tween paths and lines
```

Comment: Try installing `transformr` and try again?

Comment: Easy fix thank you!

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon, could you write that an official answer too. It can be marked as "answered " than.